# Java Web Service Consume .Net

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, web-services

**I have consume java web service to my asp.net project by right click and adding service reference.**

`public static salim.HakedisServiceClient ws = new salim.HakedisServiceClient("HakedisServiceImplPort");
 ws.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "****";
 ws.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "****";
 var lstCities = ws.getCities();`

But it has a exception like that:

System.ServiceModel.FaultException :{"Fault occurred while processing."}
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at salim.HakedisService.getCities(getCities request)
   at salim.HakedisServiceClient.salim.HakedisService.getCities(getCities request) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\website1\bdbbd757\4abd3cb7\App_WebReferences.mggi9qhe.0.cs:line 1392
   at salim.HakedisServiceClient.getCities() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\website1\bdbbd757\4abd3cb7\App_WebReferences.mggi9qhe.0.cs:line 1398
   at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\htsapp\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\WebSite1\Default.aspx.cs:line 80
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

**And webservice like that:**

```
<wsdl:definitions name="Hakedis"    targetNamespace="http://hakedis.eventhandler.archibus.com/">
<wsdl:types></wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="getFloors"></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getRooms"></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getBuildingPropertiesResponse"></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getBuildingProperties"></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getBuildingTypes"></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getBuildingTypesResponse"></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getFloorsResponse"></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getRoomsResponse"></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getCities"></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getCitiesResponse"></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getBuildingsResponse"></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getBuildings"></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="HakedisService"></wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="HakedisSoapBinding" type="tns:HakedisService"></wsdl:binding>      <wsdl:service name="Hakedis"></wsdl:service></wsdl:definitions>
```

Anyone have suggest?

Comment: Try using a tool like [`Fiddler`](http://www.fiddler2.com/) to see what data is really flowing back and forth.  You may also get a better error message in the underlying response that .NET is not picking up.

Comment: Can you add the contents of that StackTrace?

Comment: I cant read the text in the images. But it does not look like Java to me at all.

Comment: Why are you adding both `ClientCredentials.UserName` *and* `ClientCredentials.Windows`?

Comment: @his: The OP is trying to consume a Java *Web Service* using C#.Net.  Also, if you open the image in a separate window/tab, it shows normal size text.

Comment: Sorry, my eyes get old and grey.

Comment: Can you successfully call the service using a stand alone tool like SoapUI? 

It's hard to say from the screenshots but there might be an error on the java end.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set your connection up as follows:

```
 HakedisServiceClient client = null;
            ChannelEndpointElement endpoint = null;

            ClientSection clientSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client") as ClientSection;              
            ChannelEndpointElementCollection endpointCollection = clientSection.ElementInformation.Properties[string.Empty].Value as ChannelEndpointElementCollection;
            foreach (ChannelEndpointElement endpointElement in endpointCollection)
            {
                if (endpointElement.Name == "BasicHttpBinding_HakedisService") //BasicHttpBinding_HakedisService from your  config file client endpoint  entries
                {
                    endpoint = endpointElement;
                }
            }

            if (endpoint != null)
            {

                BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(endpoint.Name);

                binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1); //Set all this as appropriate
                binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                binding.AllowCookies = false;
                binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
                binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
                binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
                binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
                binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
                binding.MaxBufferSize = 100000; //as large as needed
                binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 100000; //as large as needed
                binding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;


                System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(endpoint.Address.AbsoluteUri);
                SSLAccessPolicy.AllowSSLConnection();
                client = new HakedisServiceClient(binding, address);

                SSLAccessPolicy.AllowSSLConnection(); // only if ssl enabled
                client.Open(); // Now open the client socket.
```

Hope it helps (you can debug through at first).